# Return selective rows Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to filter product using their attributes using below query

```
return Product::with('attributes')
        ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attribute_id_array,$attribute_value_array){
        for($k=0;$k<count($attribute_id_array);$k++)
        {
           $attr_id=$attribute_id_array[$k];
           $attr_val=$attribute_value_array[$k];

           $query->where(function($q) use ($attr_id, $attr_val) {
               $q->where('attribute_id', $attr_id)->where('value', $attr_val);
           });
        }
        })->paginate(10);
```

I want to check if attributes of a product exist then filter it using the loop to filter out products that are in attributes_value & attributes_id array which does not match but presently this query is not filtering through attributes.

Here are the structure of tables and relations

> Product Table :

```
 |id  | Title     | Price|
 -------------------------
 |1   | Title 1   |  5000|
 |2   | Product 2 |  7000|
```

and the other is

> product_attribute table:

```
 |id | product_id | attribute_id | attribute_name | value|
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 |1    | 1        |       5      |     Color      |  Red |
 |2    | 1        |       6      |     Size       |  XL  |
 |3    | 2        |       5      |     Color      | Green|
```

Product and Product attribute is related with following relation (In the product model):

```
 public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsAttribute::class, 'product_id ');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to validate each attribute and value combinations to be present for the resultant products, so you can put your `whereHas` clause inside the loop as

```
$products = Product::with('attributes');

for($k=0; $k<count($attribute_id_array); $k++)
{
    $attr_id=$attribute_id_array[$k];
    $attr_val=$attribute_value_array[$k];
    $products->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attr_id,$attr_val){
        $query->where('attribute_id', $attr_id)->where('value', $attr_val);
    });
}
      
$products = $products->paginate(10);
```